# Netlogo How can I export each agent's ID on the x-axis (road) at each tick to CSV?

Tags: csv, netlogo, agent

I want to compile all the agent ID on the road every tick. As already shown in the sample program below, the coordinates of all the agents on the road can be compiled by each tick on the graph. However adding agent ID information has been failed. I would like to add more agent ID information to this and export it to a CSV file. Thank you for your cooperation.

```
to plot-position
if (variety = 1)
[
 set-current-plot "Position-Time"
 set-current-plot-pen "PTA"
]
plotxy ticks xcor
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a 3D plot: time vs xcor vs who?

Comment: I want to compile with it on CSV, ticks, xcor, ID who. If it can be constructed with two-dimensional plot, x and y axes can be exported to CSV. But can we build it with 3 dimensional plot?

Comment: You can't do a 3D plot in netlogo. I wasn't sure what the question was. You may be able to just use the CSV extension. You'll need to make a list of lists. where the inner list is (list ticks xcor who) and then write it to a file. See https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html